# How does Bipolar junction transistor amplifies the voltage?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, bipolar

I was looking at [Operational amplifier](https://electronicsforu.com/resources/learn-electronics/operational-amplifier-basics) recently, so if you look at the diagram for op-amp, it's just a bunch of npn and pnp junctions. But how could they come together and work as a voltage amplifier and achieve a \$V_{out}>>V_{supply}\$?

How does Bipolar junction transistor amplify the voltage?

Comment: Why do you say $V_{out}>>V_{supply}$? Do you have a reference for that? Op amps are voltage limited by their supply.

Comment: And your next question is different. Don't ask multiple questions.

Comment: @BillN it's the same question, using an non inverting setting one could easily achieve $V_{cc}>> V_{supply}$, but the entire diagram only contain transistors and resistors. (I know how the ideal op-amp works, so as stated, how does the bipolar junction transistor amplifies the voltage.)

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate Show the diagram.

Comment: @verdelite It's in the operational amplifier hyperlink in the post, just look at the second diagram.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate Do you mean the IC 741 diagram? There +Vcc is at leg 7 and is also labeled as Vs+ on the diagram. Leg 4 is labeled with -Vcc. So +Vcc is Vsupply (or you can say +Vcc minus -Vcc is Vsupply, depending on how you want to define Vsupply). Nowhere does it say Vcc >> Vsupply.

Comment: @verdelite I meant $v_{out}>>$ supply, that was typo

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate From that diagram you can not achieve $v_{out}$ >> $V_{supply}$. As Bill N said, $V_{out}$ is limited between +Vcc and -Vcc.

Comment: Guys, the inline MathJAX tag is `\$` on EE.SE.

Comment: An op-amp can achieve Vo >> Vi - is that what you meant?

Comment: In '74 during an exam we had to design an Op Amp similar to a '741.  I wonder if they still do this.

Answer (score 1):

**The BJT or Op Amp device can never drive the output beyond the supply rails. (Vcc to Vee)**   Not possible. Even though they are called active devices, they are like 'servo'-controlled resistance and cannot boost the voltage like switched reactors (L) or transformers.

Transistor voltage amplifiers are voltage-control current-sinks (VCCS) which have high output impedance and thus voltage gain is proportional to the load resistance.

Since the Vbe vs IC is very nonlinear , it must be done with constant current sources for bias and done in many stages with methods that are more linear but lower gain.

The impedance is then reduced with several stages of  current amplifiers or emitter followers with unity voltage gain.

Comment: op Amp along could not boots voltage higher than $V_{cc}$, but Non-Inverting Amplifier constructed of op-AMP and resisters can. The entire diagram only contain transistors and resister.(with only one capacitor in the middle as in the example. )

Comment: really ;)?  please demonstrate

Comment: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/operational-amplifier-op-amp/non-inverting-amplifier.php         The op-amp = transistor + resistor + one capactor. The diagram = op-amp + resistors.

Comment: That is just DC block or AC coupled.  Not  \$V_{out}>>V_{supply}\$

Comment: _"...cannot boost the voltage like switched reactors (L) or transformers."_ ...or capacitors. But all of these components (if present) are _external_ to the op amp, which cannot boost voltage by itself.

Comment: Yes they are all external.  I agreed